# How to delete Repositories on GitHub?

Tags: github

How to delete Repositories on GitHub?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the repository, click Settings, then scroll down to "Danger Zone" and click Delete this Repository.

Comment: I havn't "Danger Zone". Do you have it now?

Comment: Are you the creator of the repository? And are you able to access the settings?

Comment: Thanks. After re-login, I can delete it.